# How to use path variable to set dictionary file in Vimscript?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I am simply trying set a dictionary file in vimscript for autocompletion. It works fine as following.

```
setlocal dictionary+=C:\Users\earik\vimfiles\pack\plugins\start\vim-baan\ftplugin\fontawesome.txt
```

What I want to do is, I want to store this long path into a variable, and use it.

```
let g:path = fnamemodify(resolve(expand('<sfile>:p')), ':h')
let g:path = g:path . '\fontawesome.txt'

setlocal dictionary+=g:path
```

Here, i am defining a global variable `g:path`. Since the fontawesome.txt file and the script file are under the same folder `~\ftplugin\`, I am finding the file location of the current script file and add fontawesome.txt at the end. When I do `echo g:path`, it is as following which looks correct.

```
C:\Users\earik\vimfiles\pack\plugins\start\vim-baan\ftplugin\fontawesome.txt
```

However, when I ask Vim `setlocal dictionary?`, I get this;

```
dictionary=g:path
```

Instead of taking the value of `g:path`, **it takes `g:path` as a string or path**. Is there workaround on this? Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `:help :let.=`, which handles expressions, instead of `:help :set+=`, which doesn't:

```
let &l:dictionary .= ',' .. g:path
```

Comment: This seems to be a much cleaner solution but I get error ; `Wrong variable type for +=`. And is it possible to do use let for local assignments?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `:execcute {expr1} ..` which executes the string that results from the evaluation of `{expr1}` as an Ex command.

```
execute 'setlocal dictionary+='.g:path
```

Comment: That's unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: `let &dictionary +=` seems to throw error E734. It's possible to use `let &dictionary = &dictionary.','.g:path`, but may not handle leading `,` and duplicated value well.